# Extjs - reset() not loading last value when trackResetOnLoad is true

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Extjs documentation [trackResetOnLoad](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/Ext.form.Basic.html#cfg-trackResetOnLoad)

> If set to true, reset() resets to the last loaded or setValues() data
>   instead of when the form was first created. Defaults to: false

In my form i set trackResetOnLoad true and In Afterrender function i updated value using setValue() and called Reset function.  trackResetOnLoad not reset to last value( setvalue()).

am i wrongly using trackResetOnLoad config option ? if possible please explain  how will reset, setValue and trackResetOnLoad will work together.
Thanks.

Fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1d8m

Note:- its not duplicate post. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007751/extjs-form-reset-not-working-as-trackresetonload-is-true) post didn't answer extract question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Field.setValue()` is called, `isDirty()` is set to **true**. To keep the form **non-dirty** after `setValue()`, you should call `resetOriginalValue()` on the corresponding field.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#username')[0].setValue ('stackoverflow');
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#username')[0].resetOriginalValue();
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#panelFormID')[0].trackResetOnLoad = true;
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#panelFormID')[0].reset();
```

Comment: Ankit your are awesome!! resetOriginalValue() fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`setValues()` does not refer to `field.setValue()`, but to `form.setValues()`.

The form resets to the last values of `form.setValues()` (as well as `form.load()` and `form.loadRecord()`, which use `form.setValues()` under the hood), as can be seen in `src/form/Basic.js`:

```
loadRecord: function(record) {
    this._record = record;
    return this.setValues(record.getData());
},

setValues: function(values) {
    var me = this,
        v, vLen, val;

    function setVal(fieldId, val) {
        var field = me.findField(fieldId);
        if (field) {
            field.setValue(val);
            if (me.trackResetOnLoad) {
                field.resetOriginalValue();
...
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. can you guide me how to detect changes after Field.setValue()